# compare value from model using pluck and string value laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

```
 $checkResult=  Auth::user()->InitialStudy()->pluck("result");
// output [["مؤهل"]]

 $r =  "مؤهل";
// output "مؤهل"

 strcmp($checkResult,$r),
// output -126
```

How to write a variable equal to this output [["مؤهل"]]?

I need to make sure that the value in "Auth::user()->InitialStudy()->pluck("result")" equal to مؤهل

Comment: nop I used == before and it's still the same get me false

Comment: ok then how can I declare variable with value = [["مؤهل"]]?

Comment: bc I have did it as collection and array and added string [[]] none of them work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $checkResult = Auth::user()->InitialStudy()->first()->result;
 $r =  "مؤهل";
    
 if($checkResult == $r){
    ...
 }else{
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```php
$checkResult = Auth::user()->InitialStudy()->pluck("result")[0][0];
// output should be "مؤهل"

 $r =  "مؤهل";
// output "مؤهل"

 strcmp($checkResult, $r),
```